# Selected features not highlighting

Tags: mesh, edit-mode

I can't seem to get selected edges and faces to highlight in edit mode.  Selected vertices show fine, and if I toggle display face centers on, I can see also see selected faces (but only because the center vertex highlights).

Things I've tried so far:
- Overlays are ON
- "Outline Selected" is ON
- Edges, Faces, and Center are all turned on under mesh edit mode

I am able to select edges and faces and manipulate them, I just can't see which ones are selected (in other words, not a problem with selection mode).  This isn't one particular file; I can start up Blender and try to edit the starting cube and no edges/faces highlight.

Blender 2.82a
AMD Radeon HD 7770 GPU

Comment: you can always revert Blender to factory setting by going to: FILE > DEFAULTS > Load Factory Settings

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I tried it, and it still has the same behavior as before.

Comment: can you share a screenshot of what's the problem and 1 example blender file to check the settings?

Comment: You can also check these settings "blender preferences" -> Themese -> Face selected (color and alpha) or Edge select

https://i.imgur.com/lzhhmYH.png

Comment: I have the same problem and I am struggling to make work.
Just to provide more information on the subject, changing to Wireframe mode, the selected face is clearly highlighted.
In my case it always happens in Solid Mode.
To reproduce the problem (or those having it), change to Wireframe mode, select a face (the face gets highlighted) and then change to Solid Mode and the face gets the general color.
Even though the selected element is not highlighted you can move it, scale etc.

Answer (score 1):

The option is settable in the Viewport Overlays.

[image]

Comment: Yes, I have edges, faces and center all turned on.

Answer (score 0):

Toggle show Overlays to 'On'. You may have accidentally switched Overlays off.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your contribution :) Would you care to [add to](https://blender.stackexchange.com/posts/199207/edit) your answer? Images, supporting links (manual reference maybe) go long way. Thanks :)

Comment: The question states that they have enabled the *overlays*, so this doesn't seem to be the answer.

Answer (score 0):

For me this was caused by the [Pose Shape Keys](https://studio.blender.org/pipeline/addons/pose_shape_keys) addon. I reported this as a bug in
https://projects.blender.org/studio/blender-studio-pipeline/issues/141